# Как вычислить значение мат. уравнения алгоритмом Горнера?

Tags: c, математика

при x=-0.7

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    double a, x, e;

    printf("x = ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    e = 2.7;

    a = pow(8 * e, 7 * x) + pow(3.2 * e, 4 * x) - pow(2.5 * e, 3 * x) - pow(7.3 * e, x) + 0.3;

    printf("A: %.4lf\n", a); 
}
```

[image: при x=-0.7]

Comment: Странно, а зачем вопрос закрыли? он в принципе интересен — как с минимальными вычислительными затратами посчитать...

Comment: @Harry про минимальность, это вы уже сами допридумываете

Comment: @Kromster А смысл схемы Горнера в чем? если не в минимизации количества вычислений?

Comment: @Harry нуу.. вы смешиваете теплое с мягким - `минимальными вычислительными затратами != using algorithm for polynomial evaluation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double z = exp(x);
double z2 = z*z;
double a = (((8*z*z2+3.2)*z-2.5)*z2-7.3)*z+0.3;
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*